# UIScrollView goes down after applicationDidBecomeActive

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I've some `UIScrollView` in a `UIControllerView`, with a `UINavigatorController` `translucent = NO`, every time that the app dismiss, when the app did become active the screen goes down an a black navigation bar appear again.

Considering the `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` doesn't raised, I capture the event in the `UIViewController`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(didBecomeActive)
                                            name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                          object:nil];
}
```

> After evaluate what happens with View, ScrollView and contentView (managed by the ScrollView) I got noticed that the scroll view moved to **y= -64**.

But still when I force to y=0 when you drag the view, a black area appears on top of the screen.

[image: Screenshot]

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your viewcontroller where your scrollview is made

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}
```